# Can't add Mapbox SDK as a module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mapbox

I'm attempting to add the Android Mapbox library as a module rather than use Gradle.  This is so we can simply modify a few lines of code to fit our use case that Mapbox didn't account for.  I clone to repo, import the module using Android Studio, and add it as a dependency to my projects build. (`compile project(':MapboxGLAndroidSDK')`) In settings.gradle we add it as well `include ':app', ':MapboxGLAndroidSDK'`.

When trying to build, however, we get the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.gc.avt.display, PID: 15839
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gc.avt.display/com.gc.avt.display.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                           at com.gc.avt.display.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at com.gc.avt.display.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at com.gc.avt.display.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gc.avt.display-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gc.avt.display-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.gc.avt.display-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmapbox-gl.so"
                                                                           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                           at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.<clinit>(NativeMapView.java:50)
                                                                           at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.initialize(MapView.java:204)
                                                                           at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:171)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                           at com.gc.avt.display.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

It looks like Mapbox is throwing when trying to run

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("mapbox-gl");
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this module running correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to get Mapbox GL working in your Android application when building from source. Depending on the feature i'd recommend request features on our [Github page](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues) or even contributing by opening a pull request with your feature. If you still want to add the source code into your application as a module, there's quite a few more steps you are missing. You'll need to make sure you are also including the C++ "core" files in your project, compiling these using `make android`, etc. You'll also need to make sure you have all the required dependencies to build the project. We have [a good guide](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/INSTALL.md) in our repo which will walk you through setup.